# Вычислить значение функции cos(x) как сумму членов ряда

Tags: python, математика

На первом фото моя задача, на двух других примеры с вычислением синуса.
Школьная задача, сделала по методичке преподавателя. Она говорит, что что-то не так, сама не знает что, а я и подавно не знаю. Буду очень признательна за помощь.
Прикладываю код, с которым "что-то не так"

```
#для pi/3
import math
x = math.pi/3
sum=x
n=1
t=(-1)**n*x**(2*n)/math.faktorial(2*n)
while abs(t)>0.1e-5:
    sum+=t
    n += 1
    t = (-1)**n*x**(2*n)/math.factorial(2*n)
print(round(x, 3), round(sum, 6), round(math.cos(x),6))

#для интервала 0...pi/2
import math
x = 0
while 1:
    sum = x
    n = 1
    t = (-1)**i*x**(2*n)/math.factorial(2*n)
    while abs(t)>0.1e-5:
        sum+=t
        n += 1
        t = (-1)**n*x**(2*n)/math.factorial(2*n)
    print(round(x, 3), round(sum, 6), round(math.cos(x),6))
    x += math.pi/6
    if x>=math.pi/2:
        break
```

Преподаватель говорила, что в первой части надо было таким же `while 1` решать, и что-то не так со второй частью.

[image: Моя задача]

[image: Пример с синусом]

[image: Пример с синусом (продолжение)]

Comment: Ошибка тут: `sum=x`.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

*Примечание:* **Первая часть** вашей программы (для pi/3) *тоже неправильная.* :-(

1. `t=(-1)**n*x**(2*n)/math.faktorial(2*n)` - не существует функция `math.faktorial()`. Измените имя `faktorial` на `factorial`.
2. Не используйте имя `sum`. *Это имя стандартной функции, которую этим перепишете.* Когда вы все равно настаиваете на этом имени, сделайте так, как принято в Питоне — добавите к нему *знак подчеркивания* (`_`). Вот так: `sum_`.
3. Инициализация в первой части *неправильна*, потому вы получили *неправильный результат.*

   Ваш код:

   ```
   sum=x
   n=1
   ```

   Должно быт:

   ```
   sum_ = 0
   n = 0
   ```

   Обратите внимание тоже на то, что для [PEP 8 - руководство по написанию кода на Python](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#section-9), я перед и за оператором присвоения (`=`) добавил пробелы.

##### Значит, **первая часть** вашей программы (немножко красивее написана) будет выглядеть так:

```
# для pi/3
import math


x = math.pi/3
sum_ = 0
n = 0
t = (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)
while abs(t) > 0.1e-5:
    sum_ += t
    n += 1
    t = (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)
    
print(round(x, 3), round(sum_, 6), round(math.cos(x), 6))
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 1.047 0.5 0.5
> ```

---

Теперь ко **второй части** вашей программы:

1. Не надо импортировать модуль `math` *дважды* в том же самом файле. Уберите `import math` из этой части.
2. Та же самая ошибка как в первой части - `n` должно начинаться с нуля. Т.е. вместо вашего

   ```
   sum = x
   n = 1
   ```

   примените

   ```
   sum_ = 0      # Более наглядно, чем ваше x = 0 и затем sum = x
   n = 0
   ```
3. Вместо `while 1:` и затем выхода из этого бесконечного цикла парой команд

   ```
   if x>=math.pi/2:
       break
   ```

   напишите просто

   ```
   while x <= math.pi/2:
   ```

   (и те последние команды для выхода из бесконечного числа уберите).

   Тем самым вы тоже исправите ошибку, когда последний результат (для pi/2) не выводился.

##### Значит, **вторая часть** вашей программы будет теперь выглядеть так:

```
# для интервала 0...pi/2
x = 0
while x <= math.pi/2:
    sum_ = 0
    n = 0
    t = (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)
    while abs(t) > 0.1e-5:
        sum_+= t
        n += 1
        t = (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)

    print(round(x, 3), round(sum_, 6), round(math.cos(x), 6))
    x += math.pi/6
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 0 1.0 1.0
> 0.524 0.866025 0.866025
> 1.047 0.5 0.5
> 1.571 -0.0 0.0
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

*Довольно длинное* выражение

```
(-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)
```

встречается в вашей программе **4 раза**. Почему не определить его как функцию

```
def term(n, x):
    return (-1)**n * x**(2*n) / math.factorial(2*n)
```

Затем вообще не надо использовать переменную `t` и **вся программа** станется более краткой и наглядной:

```
import math


def term(n, x):
    return (-1) ** n * x ** (2 * n) / math.factorial(2 * n)

# для pi/3
x = math.pi/3
sum_ = 0
n = 0
while abs(term(n, x)) > 0.1e-5:
    sum_ += term(n, x)
    n += 1

print(round(x, 3), round(sum_, 6), round(math.cos(x), 6))


# для интервала 0...pi/2
x = 0
while x <= math.pi/2:
    sum_ = 0
    n = 0
    while abs(term(n, x)) > 0.1e-5:
        sum_ += term(n, x)
        n += 1
        
    print(round(x, 3), round(sum_, 6), round(math.cos(x), 6))
    x += math.pi/6
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> 1.047 0.5 0.5
> 0 1.0 1.0
> 0.524 0.866025 0.866025
> 1.047 0.5 0.5
> 1.571 -0.0 0.0
> ```

Comment: Если вы уж так хорошо знаете PEP8, должны бы знать, что в `x = math.pi/3` тоже не хватает пары пробелов)

Comment: @Глеб: **1.** Откуда вы взяли, что я хорошо знаю PEP 8? Это не так.:-)  **2.** Вокруг оператора `/` могут быть или не быть пробелы. Потому, что **3.** PEP 8 требует пробелы вокруг только нескольких типов операторов. Цитирую: *«Всегда окружайте эти бинарные операторы одним пробелом с каждой стороны: **присваивания** (=, +=, -= и другие), **сравнения** (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), **логические** (and, or, not).»* Всё. Арифметических там нет.:-( И далее в PEP 8 как пример правильного использования приведена команда `x = x*2 - 1`, в которой нет пробелов вокруг оператора `*`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Благодарю за такой быстрый ответ и подробный разбор!!! "не существует функция math.faktorial()" - дааааааа конечно, но с этим код у меня вообще не заработал :)) но он работал, но не сохранился, поэтому я по памяти сразу сюда перепечатывала. Не совсем поняла, почему sum_ = 0
n = 0. Про sum знала, но забыла. Длинное выражение не стала заменять, чтобы было по методичке, а то вдруг придрались бы. Ещё раз спасибо огромное за помощь, преподаватель всё приняла!

Comment: @Наталия, не стоит. Вы можете принять мой ответ (клик на галочку возле него), когда он для вас полезный. См. [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Наталия: *«Не совсем поняла, почему sum_ = 0 n = 0.»* - `sum_ = 0` потому, что когда делаем сумму из многих слагаемых таким образом, что постепенно добавляем по одном слагаемом, нужно начинать с нуля. `n = 0` потому, что в отличие от функции `sin(x)`, для которой ряд Тейлора начинается с единицы (`x**1/1! - x**3/3! + ...`), ряд Тейлора для косинуса начинается с нуля (`x**0/0! - x**2/2! + ...`).